# VBA Error 91 - Cannot set my range

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have completed my very rough code, but I am in the process of optimising it.

I have defined my worksheets, but now I need to define my 2 ranges, rngTo and rngFrom. The rngTo set without a problem, but rngFrom throws an Error 91 and I cannot understand why. It should be any different than the other? Below is the part of the code which I think is relevant, but there might be some Dim's that are not utilised in this snapshot:

```
Sub Worksheet_UpdateAllItemCostData()

Dim material As Variant
Dim fndEntry, rngTo, rngFrom As Range
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim wsTo, wsFrom As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long, I As Long, J As Long
Const sPOS As String = "Pos. "

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual ' Disable
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wsTo = wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.")

wsTo.Rows("1:1").Hidden = False

lr = wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

If lr < 21 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="G:\Backoffice\Tilbudsteam\Kostdatabase\Matcost.xls", ReadOnly:=True)

Set wsFrom = wb2.Sheets("Matcost")

    For I = 21 To lr

        material = wsTo.Range("C" & I).Value

        Set fndEntry = wsFrom.UsedRange.Columns(4).Find(What:=material)

    Set rngTo = wsTo.Range("A" & I)
    Set rngFrom = wsFrom.Range("A" & fndEntry.Row)

    If Not fndEntry Is Nothing Then

            rngTo(, "B") = rngFrom(, "H")

        End If

Next I

wb2.Close
wsTo.Rows("1:1").Hidden = True

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'Enable
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: In the line `Dim fndEntry, rngTo, rngFrom As Range` , only rngFrom is defined as `Range`, fndEntry and rngTo are of type `Variant`.

Comment: Dont I feel like a fool, thx a bunch!!!

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
    Set rngTo = wsTo.Range("A" & I)
    Set rngFrom = wsFrom.Range("A" & fndEntry.Row)

    If Not fndEntry Is Nothing Then

        rngTo(, "B") = rngFrom(, "H")

    End If
```

To:

```
    If Not fndEntry Is Nothing Then

        Set rngTo = wsTo.Range("A" & I)
        Set rngFrom = wsFrom.Range("A" & fndEntry.Row)
        rngTo.Offset(0, 1) = rngFrom.Offset(0, 7)

    End If
```

Comment: Thx, and then I get a Syntax error on the "rngTo(, "B") = rngFrom(, "H") line, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I updated my answer.  `rngTo(, "B")` is not valid.  Use `rngTo.Offset(0,1)` instead.